# WP7 DesignData with custom Object

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, data-binding

I'm developping an application for Windows Phone 7.0 and I'm trying to add a sample design data file in order to have something graphic when I work with visual studio.
String or int type work fine, but custom object not.

I explain :

I have a class like this : (represent my custom object)

```
public class CustomObject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my view model :

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.Custom= new CustomObject();
        this.Custom.Title = "Hey, i'm the Runtime Custom";
    }

    public CustomObject Custom{ get; set; }

    public string TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a sample data file like this :

```
<local:MainViewModel 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModels"
    TestProperty ="I'm the Design testProperty and I work">

    <local:MainViewModel.Custom Title="Hey, i'm the Design Custom, and I don't work" />

</local:MainViewModel>
```

In the main page of my application, i have added this in the phone tag :

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData.xaml}"
```

Well, when I test with the TestProperty variable like that (`Text="{Binding TestProperty}"`), it works fine, but when I try with my object like that (`Text="{Binding Custom.Title}"`), it doesn't work...

All resources that I found can't talk about custom object.

Does anybody have any idea?

Tanks.

PS : I tryed to add the DesignData tag (what best describes my question) but i'm not allowed :(

**EDIT :** 
Without compilation, visual studio doesn't display anything, when I compil, it display `Hey, i'm the Runtime Custom`... It bypass my sample data file, but only for this custom object.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<local:MainViewModel 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModels"
    TestProperty ="I'm the Design testProperty and I work"
    xmlns:local2="clr-namespace:Project.NamespaceDefinitionOfTheCustomClass">

    <local:MainViewModel.Custom>
        <local2:Custom Title="Hey, i'm the Design Custom, and I don't work" />
    </local:MainViewModel.Custom>

</local:MainViewModel>
```

if your class "Custom" isn't defined in the same namespace of the class "MainViewModel", then add the namespace declaration like I did, else only remove that and rename local2 scope to local;

It works for me. Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the slightly simpler:

```
<local:MainViewModel 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project.ViewModels"
    TestProperty ="I'm the Design testProperty and I work">

    <local:Custom Title="Hey, i'm the Design Custom, and I don't work" />
</local:MainViewModel>
```

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately...
When I try, Visual Studio underline `local:Custom` and say : The type local:Custom was not found.